# React routing error in sub directory

Tags: reactjs, routes

I did the routing as

```
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={browserHistory }>
            <Route path='/MyAppName' component={TopContainer}>
                <IndexRoute component={Login} />
                <Route path='/main' component={MainRouteContainer} />   
                <Route path='/popup' component={StackViewContainer} />  
            </Route>
        </Router>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    )
```

and I have an apache http directory as

```
/var/www/html
```

Since there are other web apps so I need a subdirectory

```
/var/www/html/MyAppName
```

And the files in the directory above is index.html and bundle.js.

The routing code above worked fine if I access it using

```
http://www...com/MyAppName
```

The problem is once "/main" is visited, the url in the address field is turn into 
    http://www...com/MyAppName/main

At this time, a reload on the page will cause a "page not found" since there is no "main" under MyAppName (only the bundle.js).

Any suggestions?

thank

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `basename` attribute to the `Router` tag

```
<Router history={browserHistory} basename="/subdirectory/path">
```

or use the `HashRouter` in `react-router-dom`. With the hashRouter, you don't need the `basename attribute`

```
<HashRouter>
```